# Adding SwiftData model operations in Task{} block caused EXC_BAD_ACCESS using swift-async-dns-resolver

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-data

I am using [Apple's swift-async-dns-resolver](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-dns-resolver/tree/main) to collect records used for a mail troubleshooting free utility app (MX, NS, DMARC, SPF). The resolves are working. When I added the SwiftData updates to the async Task, it started randomly crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, so my guess is SwiftData may not be safe in this environment. Here is one of the functions:

```
/// Query DNS for MX record and update domain.mxRecords and domain.lastUpdate
/// - Parameter domain: SwiftData model record
func updateMxWithDomain(domain: Domain) {
    Task {
        do {
            let resolver = try AsyncDNSResolver()
            let mxRecords = try await resolver.queryMX(name: domain.domainName)
            if mxRecords.count > 0 {
                domain.mxRecords = mxRecords.map { "\($0.host) (\($0.priority))" }
            } else {
                domain.mxRecords = ["None found"]
            }
            domain.lastUpdate = Date()
        } catch {
            debugLog(object: error)
            domain.mxRecords = ["Error: \(error)"]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to write this function? Is there a discussion on using SwiftData with data collected in with async functions?

Thank you.

Comment: Note, the example code they provide, uses `let resolver = AsyncDNSResolver()`, no `try`

Comment: You could start by enabling Swift 6 concurrency check, https://www.swift.org/documentation/concurrency/

Comment: Don’t use that floating Task it is terrible practice.

Comment: @loremipsum resolver.queryMX() is an async method. updateMxWithDomain() is a sync method. How else to call it?

Comment: Update isn't sync it may look like it from the outside but it isn't behaving that way. The floating Task is being let loose and is the likely cause of the threading issues. Especially of you are doing this in many different places. Update should be decorated with async and that Task should be removed. Having tasks floating around everywhere is not going to pass Swift6 muster.

Comment: @loremipsum - got it. Reworking updateMxWithDomain() as an async method now. Thank you.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - I've just enabled in Xcode. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling Xcode concurrency check (@JoakimDanielson), I received warnings that the SwiftData model was not "Sendable". As @loremipsum noted, I re-wrote the func as async and removed the floating Task. Working func is:

```
/// Query DNS for MX record retrun an array of MX Strings
/// - Parameter domainName: domain string to query
func updateMxWithDomainName(domainName: String) async -> [String] {
    var mxRecords: [MXRecord]
    do {
        let resolver = try AsyncDNSResolver()
        mxRecords = try await resolver.queryMX(name: domainName)
        debugLog(object: mxRecords)
    } catch {
        mxRecords = [MXRecord(host: "\(error)", priority: 0)]
    }
    let mxStrings = mxRecords.map { "\($0.host) (\($0.priority))" }
    return mxStrings
}
```

It's called from a Button task that has safe access the SwitData model:

```
Button {
  Task {
    domain.mxRecords = await updateMxWithDomainName(domainName: domain.domainName)
    domain.lastUpdate = Date()
  }
} label: {
    Label("RefreshOne", systemImage: "arrow.clockwise")
}
```